# Get additional data from SSAS cube or relational database

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx

I have a situation where I'm using a SSAS cube to analyze the frequency of trips between locations. I have defined the locations as a dimension of the cube and trip frequency as a measure.

I’m creating a service that returns this data, and every time I return data from a location I also have to return several additional fields (name, geographical coordinates, and others) that are associated with the location but are not part of the dimension used in the cube.

I can think of two different ways to get that information:

1. Add all the needed fields to the dimension and get them from the cube in the same MDX query.
2. After getting the data from the cube then get the additional fields from the relational database that serves as the base for the cube.

Both these options can give me the information I need, what I don’t know is which one is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the information to the dimension would make everything easy, you just run an MDX query, and everything is there. No need to implement complex lookup logic in the service. You might consider implementing some of the additional fields as custom properties like described [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2087/defining-member-properties-for-an-attribute-in-ssas-2008), but this may make retrieving them a bit more complex, depending on the exact client interface you are using. Hence, the easiest way would be to implement them as attributes.

If you want to go the a bit more complex way, and you want to get the information in the result of a normal MDX statement, you have to add `DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Dim].[Attrib].[Prop]` before the `ON ROWS` or `ON COLUMNS` etc. of the axis containing the attribute. This includes the property in the result. How you access it depends on your client interface.

If you are using Adomd.net, you can get the properties from the `Properties` property of the members, but - according to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.member.fetchallproperties.aspx) - need to call the `FetchAllProperties` method to populate this.

There is still another method when using the properties: Defining a measure as

```
[Dim].[Attrib].CurrentMember.Properties("Prop")
```

will deliver the property value as a measure without any special implementation need on the client.

As properties need some special treatment, either for getting access to them, or by defining a measure, in many cases a normal attribute will be the best solution.

Comment: I have finally tested your suggestion but I cannot get to the property values. I am executing the MDX queries from a C# program using ADOMD.NET. The only way I'm able to get all the information I need is if I define the additional information as normal dimension attributes and add them as output columns to the query.

Comment: @lbarreira As I wrote, it is more easy to define it as normal attribute. Anyway, I added some info how you access the properties in my answer.

Comment: I have made a small test using both ways of getting the information I need. After running the tests several times (repeating the query 100 times) and changing the cube structure between both options, if I define the additional properties as custom properties then to get to the information on the client I need approximately 1600ms. If I define the properties as normal dimension attributes then the time needed is only 1000ms. With such a performance difference, I think I will go with the normal dimension attributes...

Comment: @lbarreira I added another possibility to access the properties to my answer, but I agree that in many cases, a separate attribute is the best way to implement it.

Comment: I have tried the your last suggestion, but its performance was even worse: it took twice the amount of time it takes with normal dimension attributes (2000ms compared to only 1000ms).